# Show this quad is cyclic

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles, projective-geometry, quadrilateral

Doesn't seem hard but it got me stuck:

- $I$ is the incenter of $\triangle ABC$
- $D$ the contact point of the incircle with $BC$
- $M,M'$ are the intersection of the circumcircle of $\triangle ABC$ with the perpendicular bisector of $BC$, $M'$ on the arc $BAC$
- $E = AD \cap (ABC)$
- $F,F' = M'E \cap (BCI)$

Show that $AIEF'$ lies on a circle.
[image]

I saw this problem in a blog. We know that quadrilateral $BFCF'$ is harmonic because $BM'$ and $CM'$ are both tangent lines.

Therefore line $F'F$ is symedian of $\triangle BF'C$. The blog said that this, along with the fact that $\angle DIM = \angle DEF$ implies the quad $AIEF'$ is cyclic and I don't see this implication (even tho I do see that $FF'$ is symedian and the angle equality).

If you guys can come up with any other ideas that will be cool too.

A couple facts:

- $E$ is midpoint of $FF'$
- the bisector of $\angle BF'C$ meets both: $(BCI)$ and $MM'$ at the same point.

Comment: Please attach the blog link, so that others can also see it.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon there you go: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c776104h1954382_incenterrelated_configurations_part_iv

Comment: Thanks, +1. It is baffling how one can understand so many skipped steps! The context is way out of my reach, I've struggled for some time just to get what you found! Now I will try to proceed. Naturally collinearity of $I,D,F'$ finishes it, but I can't see that from where we are now.

Comment: this is part IV of a series of theorems so it may seen kinda random but it also may use previous results and just like you I can't see it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OP mentions this [blog post](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c776104h1954382_incenterrelated_configurations_part_iv) as the inspiration for the question.  That post might be saying that $AIEF'$ is cyclic because of "radical axis", but if so it makes the error of assuming that $I,D,F'$ are collinear.

The blog post refers to a [thread](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1642775p10355749) on the problem, of which [this is one entry](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1642775p14348131). The entry defines $F'$ as collinear with $I,D$, and in a later step (after showing $AIEF'$ cyclic) demonstrates that $F'$ is collinear with $E,M'$.

Assuming $I,D,F'$ collinear the "radical axis" method amounts to computing powers of the point $D$ with respect to the circles $(ABC)$ and $(BIC)$ and the three lines $AE,BC,IF'$, giving us $$AD\cdot DE=BD\cdot DC=ID\cdot DF'.$$  By the [intersecting chords theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersecting_chords_theorem) $AD\cdot DE=ID\cdot DF'$ implies $AIEF'$ is cyclic.

After this, we can angle chase (as in the thread entry) to show that $F'$ is collinear with $E,M'$ giving us the harmonic quad setup.

Answer (score 1):

Note: AS pointed out, the following answer is invalid, as it assumes $I,D,F'$ are collinear.

The object is to show $\angle AIF' = \angle AEF’$.

[image]

$\angle AIF' = (black) + [grey] = (0.5\angle A+ \angle C + 0.5\angle B) +[90^0 – 0.5\angle B] = 0.5\angle A + \angle C + 90^0$

$\angle AEF’ = 90^0 + (purple) = 90^0 + (blue + [brown]) = 90^0 + (0.5\angle A + [\angle C])$

Comment: thanks, but when you say that $[grey] = [90^0 - 0.5 \angle B]$ you are assuming $I,D,F'$ are collinear which is what I want to prove

Comment: @hellofriends I missed that. Give me some time to think of it.

Comment: @hellofriends All I can think of is the following:- $\angle DIM = \angle DEF$ because they both are equal to $\angle AMM’$. 


Let the circle (AEF’) cut IB produced at K. Then, $\angle AKF’ = \angle DEF$.

Next, suppose that F’D produced cuts the (AEF’K) at some point J. Then, the exterior angle at J = $\angle AKF’ = \angle DIM$. From which, we can try to get a contradiction unless I  is J. Since the post is therefore not that convinving,  I will have it deleted shortly.

Comment: I think it is a good approach! Please don't delete your answer because your mistake is very common and that way people will avoid it

Comment: @Mick why wouldn't you edit your answer to say it's wrong??.....